# Help with Perl Expect

Tags: perl, expect

I am a newbie to Perl programming. Currently I have a task of understanding some code.

I have to understand Perl Expect code and in this piece of code a line is there, mentioned below:

> my $exp = new Expect;
>
> $exp->spawn("su");

My understanding is line 1 tells that we create an instance of the class and line 2, create a child process.

If anyone explain me more clearly I will be really thankful to them.

Comment: That's ... pretty much spot on. What's your question?

Answer (score 3):

First of all, let me help you help yourself:

- For help with Perl check the [perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perl.html).
- For help with Perl modules, check
  [CPAN](http://www.cpan.org/).

You are working with the Expect module here, found at [CPAN:Expect](http://search.cpan.org/~rgiersig/Expect-1.15/Expect.pod).

From a strictly syntactic point of view, all you are doing is calling two methods:

```
my $exp = Expect->new(); #Yes, the new Expect is a shorthand version
$exp->spawn("su");
```

Both methods are documented at CPAN, and they indeed **do what you *expect*** (no pun intended) them to do: the first one creates an Expect object, the second one spawns a process "su" without any parameters.

Now you can probably go using the send and expect methods to send a string to the process, or wait until it asks for input. Straight from the CPAN example:

```
# send some string there:
$exp->send("string\n");

# then do some pattern matching with either the simple interface
$patidx = $exp->expect($timeout, @match_patterns);
```